# MVP Model RxJava CompositeDisposable where do i clear?

Tags: android, rx-java, mvp, rx-android

I use MVP by http://www.tinmegali.com/en/model-view-presenter-mvp-in-android-part-2/
I use RxJava CompositeDisposable - Observable in MainModel.java
Where do I clear CompositeDisposable in my MainModel.java ?
Can I clear CompositeDisposable in method onComplete of DisposableObserver ?

```
private CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();

getObservableNote(note)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(d);

    disposables.add(d);

....
..

private Observable<Note> getObservableNote(Note noteadd) {
    return Observable.just(true).map(aBoolean -> {
        Note noteget = doLongOperationNote(noteadd);
        return noteget;
    });
}

private DisposableObserver<Note> getDisposableObserverNote() {
    return new DisposableObserver<Note>() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

            Log.d("Thread onComplete", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            disposables.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d("onError", e.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Note noteget) {
            Log.d("Thread onNext", Thread.currentThread().getName());
            mPresenter.onNoteInsertedNote(noteget);

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Of course not. If you create Observable via factory methods . It will dispose it self after onComplete(). The reason you wanna dispose yourself it's because some async work may still at background when activity/fragment died and cause a memory leak.

Comment: @Phoenix Wang Do you mean if I use interface in Actrivity or Fragment for creating Observable I do not need dispose it ?

Comment: not exactly. If you get Observable from outside your Activity to do some background work and pass an variable you don't wanna leak(ex: view) or you want to stop that work if your Activity died. you need to dispose that your self. Another situation is sometimes you just an infinity Obsevable(never onComplete). so you need to dispose yourself.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Presenter in MVP does not pass view variable into Model class. Then i do not need dispose Observable get in Model. To give your answer I would like to mark usefull.